Who owns code contributed to a license-free repository?
I have seen several different posts which suggest "code contributed to a repository inherits the license of the repository contributed to". It is not clear to me what this means when there is no license.
A repository with no license is "All rights reserved". That is, the owner of the repository is sole owner of all its code. If someone else has a repository, and I submit a pull request which is merged successfully, does that code, which is part of the repository to which they reserve all rights, belong to them?
What does the process of submitting a pull request entail, in terms of copyright ownership? It seems like submitting a pull request (asking the owner of the upstream repository to incorporate my code) involves an implied permission to incorporate my code. But what does that mean beyond that? How does ownership work on code that becomes a mix of multiple contributors' creations, after years of tweaks and adjustments?
Ultimately, if applying a license to an unlicensed repository, does the owner of the repository need permission from contributors? Why, if they reserve all rights?
If a repository has a license, such as MIT, the license will say "You may use this code as long as you do XYZ". If the contributor uses such a license, the upstream repository has that permission. What permission is granted, if a contributor's submission has no license? If I merge a pull request from someone, can they retract the code I've merged at an arbitrary time in the future?

Your question about contributions specifically to MIT licensed projects is interesting, and may warrant its own question. Bart's answer still applies & without an explicit license, the contribution must be considered ARR, and the owner of the repository would be unable to legally accept it. Copyleft licenses like the GPL do not have this problem, because the changes can only be legally made if the changes are also GPL. I asked a similar question here a few years ago: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10491/do-software-patches-ever-inherit-the-license-of-the-patched-project


A repository with no license is "All rights reserved". That is, the owner of the repository is sole owner of all its code.

It also means that this person is the only one who is allowed to make copies of the code and to make changes to the code.

If someone else has a repository, and I submit a pull request which is merged successfully, does that code, which is part of the repository to which they reserve all rights, belong to them?

When you make changes to someone else's codebase that is "all rights reserved", then you have violated the rights of the owner of the code. But the changes you made are still owned by you.
If you have made an accepted contribution to a repository without a license and you have not stated a license on your contribution either, then the two of you (yourself and the repository owner) have created a legal quagmire where neither of you is allowed to make further changes.
If you did state license terms, then by accepting your contribution, the repository owner is now obliged to abide by the license terms with regard to your contribution.

How does ownership work on code that becomes a mix of multiple contributors' creations, after years of tweaks and adjustments?

Under copyright law, each contributor owns their own contributions. This means that if there are several contributors, then the code becomes co-owned by all contributors.
This co-ownership is also why all contributors must agree to a change in license (beyond what the current license allows).

What permission is granted, if a contributor's submission has no license?

I will assume you meant that the submission does not state a license (rather than an explicit statement that there is no license). It then depends on a number of factors.
If the receiving project has an explicit policy that contributions must be made under license X, then you can assume that this submission was meant to be under that license. But it doesn't hurt to double check, especially with new contributors, if they are aware of the policy and agree with it.
The platform hosting the project's repositories can also have a policy that, unless indicated otherwise, submissions are made under the same license as what the project uses. GitHub, for example, has this policy and is often referred to as "inbound = outbound".
If neither of the above applies, then you must assume that the submission is not licensed and that you cannot incorporate it in your project without clarification from the contributor on the license terms.

It could be argued that submitting code is an implicit gift to the owner of the repository.

@MikeB, you can try to argue that, but I am not aware of a jurisdiction where it is that easy to lose your copyrights. Most require at least a positive statement from you that you are transferring your rights.

I'm inclined to agree with MikeB. I'd argue that the act of creating a PR to an "All Rights Reserved" gives the implicit acknowledgement that you are transferring the rights to the owner, and the act of the owner accepting the PR implies the owner granting permission for you to modify the repository code and accepting the transferred rights. In such case, I would think that the only rights that the author of the PR can reasonably expect to retain was the right to attribution, if applicable. It would certainly be nice if the Github Licensing Docs would clarify this, though.

If nothing else, perhaps it can be argued that, even if the author retains all rights to the contribution, they are implicitly granting a blanket license to the owner to use that code. I have to imagine that it would be hard to argue in court that the author submitted a PR that they never intended the owner to be able to make use of.

@Abion47 that may all seem common sense, but then it also seems absurd to have a public Github repo that is All Rights Reserved. The most likely interpretation is that both owner and contributor were not really giving a though to any of this, basically assuming public domain / Unlicense status. But you can't just make such interpretations. The correct conclusion is that all code you write, use, and/or modify should always be covered by an explicit license. There's really no valid excuse for not having one. (Have I at times neglected this myself? Yup...)

@leftaroundabout I wholeheartedly agree that any publicly available code repo on Github or otherwise should have an explicit license (and maybe even a CLA to cover all possible bases) precisely to avoid these legal ambiguities, but that is beside the point. This question is about when neither the owner nor the author specify a license for the code they publish, which unfortunately is common particularly among inexperienced developers.


It seems like submitting a pull request [...] involves an implied permission to incorporate my code.

Implied permission, yes. However as I think you've worked out, implied permissions are not something you want to be relying on.
The answer to all the rest of your questions is "maybe"; copyright law (very deliberately and correctly) doesn't go into that sort of detail. The only other one I'll call out is this one:

If I merge a pull request from someone, can they retract the code I've merged at an arbitrary time in the future?

The solution to this one is simple - don't merge code with unclear licensing. If someone submits a pull request where it isn't 100% clear what the copyright status of the new code is, ask them to clarify. If they don't clarify, reject the pull request, or you risk exposing yourself to all sorts of problems in the future.
(The corollary of this is of course that if you are submitting a pull request to equally be clear about the licensing of the code you are submitting)

All I'd add is that if there's no licence on the original code, you have no rights with respect to it.  This means you lack the right to create derivative works - so you shouldn't be writing updates in the first place, and the situation should never arise.  Ask for the licence to be clarified, then modify the code.

@MadHatter Don't you only lack the right to distribute/publish your derivative work? Modifying the original source-available code privately should not pose a problem.

@Bergi No, one of the rights granted by Berne convention copyright is the right to control the making of derivative works ("adaptations and arrangements").  You may never get found out, if you don't publish it, but you're still not allowed to do it.

The repository is just a publication channel, it does not change anything about the license under which somebody publishes.
Many public repositories are owned by projects or other entities that won't accept contributions unless under a specific license.
This is often done via the repository software, which won't accept or process a PR unless you have agreed to put your contribution under whatever license it requires.
However, this is by policy of the repository owner, it is not the repository itself.
To further muddy the waters, many repository hosters have a free plan but require that any repository owner that selects such a plan configure all their repos so they enforce agreement to some FOSS license.
It's still not the repo itself that applies the license, it's still the repo owner's policy, which in turn is forced by the repository hoster.
Another thing that I see is that projects don't require an agreement, assuming that you implicitly consent to putting your contribution under "the usual license of the project".
I don't know if this holds up in practice. In particular, projects without any regard for the actual license tend to have code snippets with an explicit license statement, and they end with code that is partly license A, partly license B, and partly license unknown but probably A or B but nobody cares - until somebody does care, in which case the project will be occupied with license clean-up for quite some time.
